# Group management in node/mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have question about groups management. I want to do in my app 3 different group of users with access to different places in my app. My idea is simply: in mongodb we add field to user named group where we store name of group/id.
 So there is the question. Is it good idea?(I think not) If I think good then in what way I can do it? Hashing group id/name like password or maybe there is simply framework to manage user groups? I searched a lot on google and stack and cannot find answer for me. Found only a big framework Okta and I don't need combine-harvester right now (2nd reason it is not full free). Thanks for answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just add an array attribute to user called roles, and then define access rights as a combination of those roles(groups)... RBAC

Also Okta is an Identity Management platform, what you are after here is just the AM part of IAM. just the access management.